# Как перенести часть текста на новую строку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Тэг \n не работает, пытаюсь перенести текст непосредственно в переменной, может есть какие способы. Пример:

```js
let variations = {
  r1: {
    b1: 'один' + 'два',
    b2: 'r1b2',
    b3: 'r1b3'
  },
  r2: {
    b1: 'r2b1',
    b2: 'r2b2',
    b3: 'r2b3'
  },
  r3: {
    b1: 'r3b1',
    b2: 'r3b2',
    b3: 'r3b3'
  },
}

document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]').forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('click', output, false);
})

document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(r => {
  r.addEventListener('change', output, false);
})

function output(e) {
  let radioVal = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')].find(r => r.checked == true).value;
  let buttonVal = '';
  if (e.type == 'click') {
    buttonVal = e.target.value;
    document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    buttonVal = document.querySelector('.active').value;
  }
  buttonNum = buttonVal;
  // Здесь берем получаем свойство объекта variations равное radioVal, и свойство этого свойства равное buttonVal
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = variations[radioVal][buttonVal];

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: var string='Text \n Text'
///////////////

Comment: Ох, Саша Рыбкин!

Comment: Эх, не работает

Comment: "на следующую строку" чего?

Comment: то есть один должен остаться на 1 строке допустим а 2 на следующей, такое я так понимаю невозможно?

Comment: скинь подробный код

Comment: В вопрос добавил пример

Comment: let variations = { r1: { b1:'один \n' + 'два'

Comment: Не работает, снова.

Comment: let variations = { r1: { b1:'один ' + '\n' + 'два'

Comment: Дополнил весь код.

Comment: Сейчас с миру по нитке глядишь и ответ насобирается ))))

Comment: Сейчас уже весь, ну и само собой в хтмл по id выводится result

Comment: Используйте шаблонный строки с ```````` можно с тэгом String.raw

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "One" + "<br/>" + "Two";
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня потом это выводится одной переменной она в себя вмещает вот эту и вложенную в неё

Comment: @PikachuZ Игорь показал Вам основной принцип. Вы можете в `variations` сделать запись `b1: 'один' + '<br>два'` В этом случае выводя значение - `два` при выводе будет записываться с новой строки.

Comment: @PikachuZ Пример: `<div id="result"></div>
<script language="JavaScript">
    let variations = {
        r1: {
            b1: 'один' + '<br> два',
            b2: 'r1b2',
            b3: 'r1b3'
        },
        r2: {
            b1: 'r2b1',
            b2: 'r2b2',
            b3: 'r2b3'
        },
        r3: {
            b1: 'r3b1',
            b2: 'r3b2',
            b3: 'r3b3'
        },
    };
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = variations.r1.b1;
</script>`